# ParamQuery Grid (pqgrid) Coldfusion json to jquery

Tags: json, parsing, coldfusion, cfc

OK - not sure if anyone has an answer to this. I assume there are others that would like this info as well...

I'm working with pqgrid and would like to easily get the json sent from a cfc into the "data" for the grid. I've tried many things without luck. It always throws an error about parsing the json. My last attempt is as follows:

CFC:

```
<cffunction name="getResources" access="remote" 
       returntype="query" HINT="Get All Resources" returnFormat="JSON">

    <cfquery name="get_resources" datasource="#Session.ODBC#">
        SELECT *
        FROM Resources
        ORDER BY resourcename
    </cfquery>
    <CFRETURN get_resources>
</cffunction>
```

JQUERY:

```
dataModel: {               
dataType: "JSON",
location: "remote",
recIndx: "resourceid",
url: "/cfc/Exercise.cfc?method=getResources&queryFormat=column",
         getData: function (response) {
                return { data: response.DATA };
         }
},
```

**EDIT:**

The JSON being returned is correct I believe - Assume that pqgrid expects it some other way:

```
{ 
  "ROWCOUNT":10
  , "COLUMNS":[ "RESOURCEID"
                 , "FK_EXERCISEID"
                 , "FK_SIMULATORGROUPID_OWNE‌​R"
                 , "FK_SIMULATORID_OWNER"
              ]
  , "DATA":{ 
        "RESOURCEID":[624,594,593,596,628,513,514,515,‌​516,517]
        , "FK_EXERCISEID":[6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6]
        , "FK_SIMULATORGROUPID_OWNER":[31,25‌​,25,25,25,26,26,26,26,26]
        , "FK_SIMULATORID_OWNER":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
     }
 }
```

Comment: If you run `/cfc/Exercise.cfc?method=getResources&queryFormat=column` does it seem to be returning the JSON you expect?

Comment: The JSON being returned is correct I believe - Assume that pqgrid expects it some other way: {"ROWCOUNT":10,"COLUMNS":["RESOURCEID","FK_EXERCISEID","FK_SIMULATORGROUPID_OWNER","FK_SIMULATORID_OWNER"],"DATA":{"RESOURCEID":[624,594,593,596,628,513,514,515,516,517],"FK_EXERCISEID":[6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6],"FK_SIMULATORGROUPID_OWNER":[31,25,25,25,25,26,26,26,26,26],"FK_SIMULATORID_OWNER":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]}}

Comment: getting closer to figuring this out... changed the cffunction to return a string and changed the return to <CFRETURN SerializeJSON(get_resources)> ... closer ...

Comment: You should not need to do that. Simply adding returnFormat=json to the URL (or having it in the function definition as you do) should be enough. It is likely that the JSON being returned is simply not in a format that you are a) expecting or b) useful to how you are trying to use it. You may be better off massaging the data into an array of structs before returning it.

Comment: The value of `response.DATA` is simply an JS object where each property is the name of one of the columns in the query and the value is an array of values for that particular column. This is neither useful nor intuitive.

Comment: Also....you should not use `SELECT *` in queries. It is better to list out only the columns that you need. This will result in less, and only the pertinent, data being passed around.

Comment: @Angela - FYI, to include [more details](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21786121/paramquery-grid-pqgrid-coldfusion-json-to-jquery#comment32962767_21786121), just [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21786121/edit), so the information will be more visible to others, not to mention easier to read :) Then delete the redundant comment.